# Infrared Wavelength Measurement and Identification

Tags: measurements, infrared-radiation

I have a heat panel that I would like to use with animals, so would like to know what IR radiation (Ie.A, B or C) it is putting out. I have spoken to the manufacturer but they do not know. What is the best way to test this, or where to get it tested?

Thanks

Comment: Your "heat panel" probably is a pretty good approximation of what physicists call a _black body radiator._ If you know it's surface temperature, then you can predict its emission spectrum by using [Planck's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). But, if what you're mainly worried about is "IR A" (bad for eye health, or so I've heard), I _suspect_ that it's not going to be a problem if the panel is not glowing red with heat.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to answer. I'm not so much worried about IR A, but would like to know what it is producing as different bands will be beneficial for different species. The surface temperature is 95.5 degrees centigrade. But in all honesty, I don't know how to calculate Planck's law using the 95.5.